# Align cells in rows *and* columns in a flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there any way to align cells in rows **and** columns (like in a table) using flexbox ?

To make things clear, what I would like is to align cells in the table below.

Of course I could add some `flex: XXX` but the problem is I don't want to fix the width of the columns.

I have gotten used to flex fixing everything but I feel kind of stuck... So is there no solution apart from going back to `display: table` or html `<table>`s...?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yannick1976/hz3x5z4b/2/) if you want to play with it :)

```css
.myCell {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.myTable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.myRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="myTable">
  <div class="myRow">
    <div class="myCell">ROW 1, CELL 1</div>
    <div class="myCell">ROW 1, CELL 2</div>
    <div class="myCell">ROW 1, CELL 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myRow">
    <div class="myCell">A LONGER CELL</div>
    <div class="myCell">ROW 2, CELL 2</div>
    <div class="myCell">ROW 2, CELL 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `flex: 1` to `myCell`?

Comment: @Michael_B that gives all columns the same size :(

Comment: Then maybe consider a primary flex container (`row`), with three flex items. Each flex item is a nested flex container (`column`). Then fill up those columns with your cells. Each column will be as wide as the widest cell.

Comment: The future replacement for CSS Table is CSS Grid, not Flexbox ... That said, you can make Flexbox behave as a table, kind of, but not replace it fully ... And as you seem to look for a column/row layout, use CSS Table (and that is not _going back_)

Comment: How do you want them to displayed if not with flex:1. ...flex:1 to mycell is a good solution though

Comment: @Michael_B then the problem is the same if cells heights are different...

Comment: @LGSon your comment answers my question. I'll accept it if you make it an answer.

Comment: @Michael_B If you have a sample/post/answer showing the best way achieving a table like flexbox layout, drop me a link and I'll add a reference link to it in my answer ... or just add it yourself

Comment: @LGSon, I only have time to comment right now. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The future replacement for `CSS Table` is [`CSS Grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), not `Flexbox`.

That said, you can make `Flexbox` behave as a table, kind of, but not replace it fully,  and as you seem to look for a column/row layout, use `CSS Table` (and that is not *going back*)